# Do you recognise the software used to make this map?

Tags: software-recommendations

What software or template does Max Fisher use to create his maps for the Washington Post?

Do you recognise the software used to make this map?

As an example:
[image]

More examples here:
http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/01/13/40-more-maps-that-explain-the-world/

Comment: As long as Answers to this Question are based on deduction, with evidence to back them up, rather than just opinions, then I think it can stay open.  If it seems to attract opinions then I will probably join the Close vote.

Comment: The reality is that *any* GIS software could make that map, so the significance of the actual package in use is reduced.

Comment: Is your real question which projection was used?

Answer (score 2):

I know Avenza's MAPublisher is capable of creating maps like those you've indicated. Additionally the Washington post is listed as a customer of Avenza : http://www.avenza.com/customers